# Column order after multi-index unstack

Tags: pandas, stack, multi-index

Output after unstacking data. I unstacked using multi-columns
unstack(['MarketDate','Class'])

```
MarketDate    2017/08/19 2017/08/18         2017/08/19
Class             Onpeak     Onpeak Offpeak    Offpeak
Constraint_ID                                         
634              -221.65    -165.28 -116.55    -237.97
644                 0.00       2.22    0.00       0.00
1049             -702.05    -936.26 -317.45    -181.72
1281                0.00      -4.68    0.00       0.00
1607             -136.12     -84.74  -31.44     -65.91
```

What I need to see in the output is MarketDate and below it Onpeak and Offpeak, not MarketDate for Onpeaks first and then Offpeaks later.

This is important for further processing.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a paste of your expected output?

Comment: I can't paste the format in the comments. How would I do it? Basically, you see column 1 above (2017/08/18, Onpeak), that should be in column 2 place. I did not want to use column manipulation.

Comment: Edit the question.

Comment: sorry meant to type this: Basically, I am looking for following column order: [(2017/08/19, Onpeak), (2017/08/19, Offpeak), (2017/08/18, Onpeak), (2017/08/18,Offpeak)]. I did not want to use column manipulation if possible.

Comment: Try df.sort_index(axis=1).

Comment: perfect thanks...I just needed to set ascending=False

Comment: Great.  You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,  you need `sort_index` with `axis=1`.

```
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Scott - it still puts onpeak dates next to each other. Just that the levels got swapped. I am looking for the dates to remain on level0 but onpeak and offpeak to come together?

Comment: I think you next too add. .sort_index(axis=1).